# Find Parent By Child One to Many Relation Grails

Tags: grails, foreign-keys, grails-orm

I have this classes:

```
class Parent{
    static hasMany = [children:Child]
}

class Children{
    static belongsTo = [Parent]
}
```

I want to do something like

```
Parent.findByChildren(ChildInstance)
```

In the database there is a table with the relationship id's, but I don't know how to access to it.

But that doesn't work, which is the proper way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Children class belongsTo clause :

```
class Children{
    static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
}
```

This will allow you to access a child's parent instance : `childInstance.parent`

Answer (score 0):

First I would change the relationship in Children domain to

```
static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]  // suggested by @bassmartin
```

or

```
Parent parent
```

both does the same thing.

Once you have the ChildInstance and the reference to the parent, you can simply do

```
ChildInstance.parent     // returns instance of parent
```

Similarly, if you want to find all the children of a parent, you can do

```
parent.children          // return an array of children which you can iterate over.
```

Comment: Child has no reference to the parent and what I want to avoid is to iterate over all the parents in the database.